# Does loading the HTML of a site generate traffic for that site?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-asynctask

I load HTML into a string in my Android app with the following code in an AsyncTask:

```
            String html = "";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                str.append(line);
            }
            in.close();
            html = str.toString();
```

where the string "html" holds the HTML code of whatever URL I'm loading. My question is rather simple, does loading this HTML count as traffic on that website (so say they had ads, would those ads count that as a page view?) or does it not count as it's only reading the HTML of the site?

Comment: short answer is Yes. long answer is it won't generate any useful traffic to that site regarding advertising. it is just loading the html not the ads.

Comment: OK, so said website won't receive revenue for those ads loading. Is there any way to load the site (ads included) that won't eat up a ton of memory? I tried loading it all in a hidden webview but that caused outOfMemory errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't do this from one computer. The issue isn't so much the loading of the webpage but the actual adverts. I know for a fact that with Google AdSense they only allow one hit per IP address and if they see a sudden amount of traffic on the same IP on the same webpage they will just block the account so that no more adverts receive revenue.